# linux namespace, How to connect internet in network namespace?

Tags: linux, networking, namespace

I want to test linux network namespace.

The current problem is I cannot connect internet in the namespace

here is my commands:

1 Create network namespace netns1, create a pair of veths (A and B) set B into namespace

```
ip netns add netns1
ip link add A type veth peer name B
ip link set B netns netns1
```

2 create a bridge to connect veth A

```
brctl addbr bridge0
ip addr add 172.17.42.1/16 dev bridge0
ip link set dev bridge0 up
brctl addif bridge0 A
ip link set A up
```

3 In namespace, set the network

```
ip netns exec netns1 ip link set dev B name eth0
ip netns exec netns1 ip link set eth0 up
ip netns exec netns1 ip addr add 172.17.42.99/16 dev eth0
ip netns exec netns1 ip route add default via 172.17.42.1
```

When I ping google, I got this:

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

**How can I connect to the internet in this namespace ?**

Here are some other details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you

**update 1**

I also try to set the NAT:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16  -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j MASQUERADE

But still unknown host

Comment: None of this is helping: What are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` ? If ping says 'unknown host' it means it can't resolve www.google.com, which can have a whole set of different reasons.

Answer (score 6):

Think of a network namespace as another computer.
Think of a veth pair as two Ethernet cards with a crossover cable between them.

There are three main ways to connect a network namespace to the Internet, NAT, conventional IP routing, Ethernet bridging.

NAT is generally the easiest to set up because it works with any type of upstream internet connection and doesn't require the cooperation of the upstream network.

For NAT to work several things need to be in place.

1. The default gateway needs to be set up in the secondary network namespace (you appear to have done this)
2. IP forwarding needs to be enabled in the main network namespace (you have not shown how this setting is set).
3. The iptables rules in the main network namespace need to allow the traffic to pass (on the kernel side this is ok by default but some firewall software may have set up rules that block forwarding).
4. An appropriate SNAT or masqurade rule needs to be in place in the main network namespace (you appear to have done this).

You also need to ensure that an appropriate /etc/resolv.conf is available for programs in the secondary network namespace. Remember that even if you bring up the local loopback interface in the secondary network namespace (which you should do) it is still local to each network namespace.

It is best to ping/traceroute by IP address when initially setting up networks to seperate name resoloution issues from general connectivity issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to diagnose a possible network issue, *don't* try pinging an FQDN. Heck, don't use ping at all.

Try this instead: `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`

This will yield more useful information for two reasons:

1. it doesn't require a functioning resolver (if you can't get to the internet, you can't do a DNS lookup, so you get 'unknown host', but if your resolver isn't working you'll get the exact same answer even if your connection is fine).
2. It will attempt to get a response from every host along what it thinks should be the route to 8.8.8.8, which will show you *where* the connection goes awry as opposed to simply *whether* it does.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are getting `ping: unknown host www.google.com` because your name resolution if failing because of the network connectivity issues mentioned below.  However, you probably want to double check that this isn't just a DNS issue by pinging an IP address.

From what you've provided, it looks like you haven't added a physical interface to the network bridge.  Without a physical interface on the bridge, traffic on that bridge has no way onto the rest of the network.

An alternative to adding a physical interface to the bridge, would be to turn on IP forwarding and set up NAT rules with `iptables`.

Comment: Thank you, i am trying to set NAT rules, it would be great if you can provide more details about this.

Comment: I try like this: 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16  -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j MASQUERADE

But still unknown host

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the lo interface up? I have seen networking not working in a namespace when lo is not up, so try this:

> ip netns exec netns1 ip link set lo up